# Access to Common Data Service without user login through Python Azure function

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I've been trying to give an Azure function access to send http requests to my Common data service, but have been unable to set the access correctly

Currently, my permissions are setup with access to Dynamics CRM (https://admin.services.crm.dynamics.com/user_impersonation), but it is set to 'Delegated', rather than 'Application'. 'Application' is greyed out here.

[image]

Currently, my function is as such:

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    config = json.load(open("parameters.json", "r"))

    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        config["client_id"], authority=config["authority"],
        client_credential=config["secret"]
    )

    result = None
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes=config["scope"], account=None)

    if not result:
        logging.info("No suitable token exists in cache. Getting a new one from AAD.")
        result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=config["scope"])

    if "access_token" in result:
        print(result["token_type"])
    else:
        print(result.get("error"))

    http_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token'],
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    data = requests.get(config["endpoint"], headers=http_headers, stream=False)
```

This currently returns code 403 Forbidden. How should security & permissions be setup for this example when using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamics CRM API doesn't support **Application permissions**, that's why you can not choose application permissions when grant permissions in azure portal.

The workaround is using **Server-to-Server authentication**. You will need to create an application user. This application user will be given access to your environment's data on behalf of the user who is using your application.

Reference:

[Build web applications using Server-to-Server (S2S) authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/build-web-applications-server-server-s2s-authentication)

[Application User creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/use-single-tenant-server-server-authentication#application-user-creation)